# Can the extensions Hidden in the Chrome Menu be reordered?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

We know that extensions in the Chrome *Toolbar* can be rearranged. But can extensions Hidden in the Chrome Menu also be rearranged somehow?

Without some setting, modification or add-on, they seem to be permanently fixed.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly... As both hidden and showing extensions can be rearranged by click and drag.

Comment: @Klinghust Not possible for me in macOS using the latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, with click and drag.

[image: Rearrange Extensions Chrome]